# Binding Kendo UI Dataviz chart series to specific model

Tags: json, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

Is it possible to create a Kendo UI DataViz chart from a remote datasource with a structure such as

```
    "gender": [
        {"male": 23421}, 
        {"female": 24376},
        {"unknown": 324}
        ],
```

Instead of using (from the example in the documentation)

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  categoryAxis: {
    field: "year"
  },
  series: [
    { field: "value" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { year: "2012", value: 1 },
    { year: "2013", value: 2 }
  ]
});
</script>
```

I would like to use a data source formatted as

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  categoryAxis: {
    field: "year"
  },
  series: [
    { field: "value" }
  ],
  dataSource: [
    { "2012": 1 },
    { "2013": 2 }
  ]
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's a straightforward transformation in Javascript.

```
convertDataSource = function(dataSource) {
  for(i in dataSource) {
    (y = {})[dataSource[i].year] = dataSource[i].value;
    dataSource[i] = y;
  }
  return dataSource;
}
convertDataSource([ { year: "2012", value: 1 }, { year: "2013", value: 2 }])
// [ { "2012": 1, "2013": 2}
```